# How to access form element in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to access an element in javascript function so as to autocomplete the user search, using [autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/autocomplete/#entry-examples) API.
It is not working as the JS code is not able to access that element.
My javascript code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#q").autocomplete({
    source: "/api/get_drugs/",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
</script>
```

My reference for [search](http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/).

---

My Form:

```
<form id = "myForm" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
    <input style="width:340px;height:37px;" size="30" type="text" id = 'q' name = 'q' placeholder="Search products or categories"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" >
</form>
```

Here the input target field has id  and name- 'q'.

Comment: whats tag with id `drugs`

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is? How does the code fail? Are you getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: it was a mistake, i have edited it in the question

Comment: You've changed the selector from '#drugs' to '#q' now. Does that not fix the problem?

Comment: I;m not getting error, just that it is not being loaded( the javascript function is somehow not working), because it's not able to access that element.

Comment: Nope, it didnt, I just pasted it from the source and not my code by mistake. @Andy

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, maybe *I* should've read the docs... :P

Comment: Yes @ChrisG, source is a url(which is a string)

Comment: I dont need the data whatsoever. @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bellow code works perfect . Now make sure that the response you are getting from the api is an **array** .

Or else do one thing , store the response of API in some variable and assign that variable to key Source . 
For example :

```
source : apiResponseVariable //must be array .
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#q").autocomplete({
    source: ["hello" , "how"],
    

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>GnG</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id = "myForm" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
    <input style="width:340px;height:37px;" size="30" type="text" id='q' name = 'q' placeholder="Search products or categories"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You can checkout my running run .